# Year + Month ComboBox VB

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Right now im trying to display year + month in 1 combobox using VB. I manage to combine it but i need to display it from current year & month until past 2 past year ago. The expected output should be display like this.

Expected Output display on combobox :

```
2017/10
2017/9
2017/8
2017/7
2017/6
2017/5
2017/4
2017/3
2017/2
2017/1
2016/12
2016/11
2016/10
2016/9
2016/8
2016/7
2016/6
2016/5
2016/4
2016/3
2016/2
2016/1
```

Here in my current code and output.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ComboBox1.Text = Date.Now.Year & "/" & Date.Now.Month
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(Date.Now.Year & "/" & Date.Now.Month - i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Output :

```
2017/10
2017/9
2017/8
2017/7
2017/6
2017/5
2017/4
2017/3
2017/2
2017/1
```

How I can extend it to the past year and month?

Comment: I recommend you use a `DateTimePicker` instead, with the `CustomFormat` property set to `"yyyy/MM"`.

Comment: I cant use dateTimePicker for my application. Its not suitable for my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an array of `Strings` containing the year and month for the current and previous months you can do this:

```
Dim arr = Enumerable.Range(0, count + 1).
                     Select(Function(n) Date.Today.AddMonths(-n).ToString("yyyy/M")).
                     ToArray()
```

where `count` is the number of months you want to go back.  You can then assign that array to the `DataSource` of your `ComboBox`.

Using code more like your original, that would be:

```
For i = 0 To count
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(Date.Today.AddMonths(-i).ToString("yyyy/M"))
Next
```

Note that here we use `count` rather than `count + 1` because this is an upper bound where previously it was an actual count, which will be 1 greater.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretend to be an answer, but just an addition to @jmcilhenney's answer.
In case you want use information of selected month, you can use data-binding and created class for month.

```
Public Class Month
    Public ReadOnly Property Year As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property Month As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property Formatted As String

    Public Sub New(date As Date)
        Year = date.Year
        Month = date.Month
        Formatted = date.ToString("yyyy/M")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Create collection of months and set it to `ComboBox.DataSource`

```
Dim today = Date.Today
Dim months = Enumerable.Range(0, count + 1).
                       .Select(Function(i) new Month(today.AddMonths(-i))
                       .ToArray()

ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Formatted" ' Name of property to be used as Text for ComboBox
ComboBox1.DataSource = months
```

Then when user selects month

```
Private Sub ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim comboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
    Dim selectedMonth = DirectCast(comboBox.SelectedItem, Month)

    'Now you have access to year and month properties
    selectedMonth.Year
    selectedMonth.Month
End Sub
```